# Specify number of digits in java

Tags: java, numbers, format

Suppose you have:

```
int a = 3;
```

And I want to specify that the number of digits is 5. So that when I print it the output is:

```
00003
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `int` stores only the value, no formatting information. To show or preserve leading zeros you have to use a String.

```
 System.out.println(String.format("%05d", a));
```